# Passing javascript string variable into nlapiSearchRecord filter

Tags: suitescript

I'm working on a Suitelet to apply landed costs (through a .csv file) to item receipts. This code below is iterating through an array of PO numbers to build out a formula(number) to pass into `nlapiSearchRecord()`.

I'm having trouble getting the search to fire when passing part of the search filter in from a variable. I've tried passing various sizes of string with and without double or single quotes (see commented out sections for an idea) and now I'm simply passing one variable, `testNumber`, into the search string. It's still failing giving me this error:

> SSS_INVALID_SRCH_FILTER_EXPR_OBJ_TYPE
> Malformed search filter expression: Unrecognized object type.

The complete line is supposed to be

```
["formulanumeric: case when {number} = 'PO476' or {number} = '294' then 1 else 2 end","equalto","1"], 

        for(var i = 0; i<poNumbers.length; i++) {

            if(i < (poNumbers.length - 1)) {

                poFormula += "{number} = '"+poNumbers[i]+"' or ";

            }

            else {
                poFormula += "{number} = '"+poNumbers[i]+"'";
            }

        }

        //poFormula(string) --> {number} = 'PO481' or {number} = 'PO476' or {number} = '294' or {number} = 'PO440' or {number} = 'PO441'

        //var searchFormulaStart = "formulanumeric: case when "+poFormula+" then 1 else 2 end";
        //var sfMiddle = "equalto";
        //var sfEnd = "1";

        var testNumber = "'PO476'";

        var purchaseorderSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("purchaseorder",null,
        [
           ["mainline","is","T"],
           "AND",
           ["type","anyof","PurchOrd"],
           "AND",
           ["formulanumeric: case when {number} = "+testNumber+" then 1 else 2 end","equalto","1"], 
           //[searchFormulaStart,sfMiddle,sfEnd],
           "AND",
           ["type","anyof","PurchOrd"]
        ], 
        [
           new nlobjSearchColumn("internalid",null,null)
        ]
        );
```

The idea is that I need to return all the POs included in the .csv so I can get their internal ids. Later in the code, I will pass these ids into another search against item receipts, finding all receipts created from those POs. Once I have those, I can apply freight costs to those receipts.

```
       var itemreceiptSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("itemreceipt",null,
            [
               ["type","anyof","ItemRcpt"], 
               "AND", 
               ["mainline","is","T"], 
               "AND", 
               ["createdfrom","anyof", poInternalIds]
            ], 
            [
               new nlobjSearchColumn("tranid",null,null)
            ]
            );
```

Can anyone confirm if there's some undocumented bug or something with passing part of a search string in from a variable like this? Alternatively, given PO numbers and freight costs, is there a better way to apply landed costs to item receipts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with help from some folks on Slack. Rather than trying to concatenate variables into the filter string, I'm now creating the entire filter array in a forEach() loop as shown below.

I'm still not sure why the Netsuite API didn't like my search formatted with a concatenation, but this is a much cleaner solution anyway.

```
        for(var i = 0; i<freightCosts.length; i++) {

            poNumbers.push(freightCosts[i].PO);

        }

        poNumbers.forEach(function(tranid){

            filters.push(["tranid", "is", tranid]);
            filters.push("or");

        });
        // remove the last "or"
        filters.pop();

        var purchaseorderSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("purchaseorder",null,
        [
           ["mainline","is","T"],
           "AND",
           ["type","anyof","PurchOrd"],
           "AND",
           [filters]
        ], 
        [
           new nlobjSearchColumn("internalid",null,null)
        ]
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough, I ran into this exact issue just last week. It appears to be a bug in the Rhino Javascript engine that Netsuite uses. The workaround to get it to work is to wrap your concatenation in a `String()`:

```
[String("formulanumeric: case when {number} = "+ testNumber + " then 1 else 2 end"), "equalto", "1"]
```